# Unit testing with ESP-IDF

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, esp32

Currently, I am working with an ESP-IDF and try to get unit testing to work.

I already found https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guides/unit-tests.html, but there is a point which I don't understand.

But first, let me explain my setup:

- I work under Windows and have a MSYS32 shell.
- My `IDF_PATH` points to ~/esp-idf, where my esp-idf suite sits.
- My projects sit in ~/project_dir/subdir, however. They work as they should.

If I follow the instructions in the unit test guides, I can build the test cases which are built into the system. But it does not find the unit tests of my application. This is clear, as they sit somewhere completely else.

What am I supposed to do now? Perferrably without tampering with the default unit test app too much?

I can see several approaches, but I don't know what is the intended way to add own components resp. their test cases into the said app:

- Should I add the project paths somewhere into the unit test app?
- Should I copy the unit test app and add it to my projects?
- Should I create a folder in my project and add a link to the unit test app?

Comment: I don't see how this question is "too broad". It is about a concrete framework and its ability to run unit tests and how to include own test cases into the unit test app. There is a very small gap in the documentation

Comment: I struggle with the same documentation. It appears to me that it is targeted to running esp-idf own unit tests and not to users who build apps using esp-idf. I think an example with a few working tests would be great. I'll come back and add a link in case I find sth useful.

Comment: @mark Great, thank you. I think it should be as well targeted to users who build components. Thus my question.

Comment: I got a [reply to my forum question](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?p=34262#p34262), it seems they've addressed this with an example project but haven't updated the docs.

Comment: @detly Great! I will check this as soon as I'll be back to work (not sure if that happens this year again, but definitely in January!)

Comment: @glglgl If you're on a Linux distro, note that there's another [toolchain issue](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/2754) that might cause problems. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ESP-IDF unit test setup is actually designed for testing its own internal components, and to help anyone adding to those.

To unit test your own project separately, take a look at this [example project](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/system/unit_test/README.md) that shows how to create a Unity unit test application alongside a proper project. Note that the project itself is called `unit_test`, so the test application is `unit_test_test`. The component is called `testable`. (I'm flagging that because it confused me; interpret `unit_test` like you might read `example_app` or `myproject`.)

Failing that, [this ESP forum post](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2867&p=34258#p13466) also gives a way to include your components in their unit test app:

```
make -C ${IDF_PATH}/tools/unit-test-app EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS=/path/to/my_proj/components TEST_COMPONENTS=mycomponent
```